# deciding factors of BaaS Providers

Tags: mobile, backend

I am trying to find out which BaaS provider is right for me.

If I'm understanding right, all the famous ones (Kinvey, Firestack, Parse, etc.)

provides basically same features ( data storage, push notification, app analysis and more) but what are the deciding factors to choose one over the other?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: start with what important to your app current and projected future requirements, and see how the requirements are mapped to the provided functionality, after pick one with good balance between price and feedback  by community on support and usability

Answer (score 3):

Ideally the deciding factors for a BaaS should be the following :

1. **Vendor-Lockin** : Is the BaaS provider using open source software ? So that even if it were to shut down, you could move on with your life.
2. **Data and Infrastructure** : Do you own your own data and infrastructure ? Or does the BaaS service own and manage it for you ? Ideally, you want to own your own data and infrastructure.
3. **Cost and Scaling** : How tough is it to scale while using this BaaS service and how feasible is the cost for scaling ?
4. **Language** : If you wanted to write your own custom back-end api, do you have the freedom to do it in the language of your own choosing ? Or are you forced to use the language that the BaaS supports ?
5. **PaaS** : According to Wikipedia, Platform as a service (PaaS) is a category of cloud computing services that provides a platform allowing customers to develop, run, and manage applications without the complexity of building and maintaining the infrastructure typically associated with developing and launching an app. It will be ideal to have ONE service be both your BaaS and PaaS provider.

Having said the things above, I would urge you to try out [Hasura](http://www.hasura.io/) which ticks off positive on all the above mentioned points. Do check out [compare](http://compare.beta.hasura.io) to see how it fares compared to other providers like Firebase, Heroku etc. And finally, check out [explore](http://explore.beta.hasura.io) to get a feel of what you can do with Hasura (You will end up with your own Blog web app as well as a todo web app in under 15 mins, deployed live)

Disclaimer: I work at Hasura.